# Shifting TikZ labels relative to default "below" placement

Tags: tikz-pgf

In a TikZ figure, I have the labels placed below the nodes according to the syntax `node [label=below:x]`. However, some of the labels would need slight horisontal adjustment. The solution which seemed promising was using `xshift`, according to the syntax `node [label={[below, xshift=1pt]{x}}]`. However, this offsets the label vertically, and I do not understand why.

In the example below, is there some way to give the second label (a bullet) the exact same placement as the first one (relative to the end of the line), only shifted 1pt to the right?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \draw
        (0,0) node [label=below:$\bullet$] {} -- 
        (2,0) node [label={[below, xshift=1pt]{$\bullet$}}] {};
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Just to make sure: You do know that `$\bullet$` is a bad way to draw a filled circle? -as you have bad control over exact placement and size. A `label` is a `node`, so it does normally not make sense to place it under an empty node - just use the node itself.

Comment: `below:` is just a shorthand for an angle - the same as `-90:` or `270:` or `south:`

Comment: @hpekristiansen I understand that my minimal example is odd; it was just my way of making the issue stand out clearly. In my real life problem I have a graph with reasonable labels!

Comment: `below:` is something different than a `below` (which sets `anchor=north`) in the optional arguments. If there's no label position given before the `:` (or no `:` at all), the default label position is used (which is `above` which also sets `anchor=south`). Make nodes and labels visible (by `draw`ing them) to see the relationship between them. Anyway, what are you trying to do? Why text bullet? Why an empty node? Why a label? Where should the dots be? Where should the line start and end? What are the relations between dots and line?

Comment: @Qrrbrbirlbel The bullets are just placeholders for the labels of my graph. I want the second label to have the same placement as the first (relative to the above node) except for a horizontal shift.

Comment: Then do `label={[xshift=<distance>]below:$\bullet$}`.

Comment: @Qrrbrbirlbel Thanks, this solved the problem. If you have opportunity to also elaborate why it works while my original attempt doesn't, I would consider it a very good answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Before I get into any explanation, let's look at your example with drawn nodes:

```
\tikz[nodes=draw, every label/.append style={help lines, draw}]
  \draw
    (0,0) node [label=below:$\bullet$] {} -- 
    (2,0) node [label={[below, xshift=1pt]{$\bullet$}}] {};
```

[image]

The `below:` label is placed with its top (`anchor=north`) at the bottom (`.south`) of its parent node.

The other label is placed with its top (`below` → `anchor=north`) at the top (`.north`) of its parent node (or `above` it). Why the top? Because the default [`label position`](https://tikz.dev/tikz-shapes#pgf./tikz/label:position) is `above`.

---

There is a difference between a label position `below` and the key `below`.

Remember that the full syntax of the `label` key is

```
label={[<options>]<position>:<text>}
```

Where both `[<options>]` and `<position>:` are optional. If the `<position>:` is missing, the last given value to `label position` is used. However, with `<options>` you can also set a label position:

```
label={[label position=below]<text>}
```

but it won't overwrite a `<position>:` specification.

The key `below` does something else than the label position `below`.
In its barest form it just sets `anchor=north`. (And then there's `below=<distance>` which is short for `anchor=north, yshift=-(<distance>)` and then there's the [`positioning`](https://tikz.dev/tikz-shapes#pgf.positioning)-powered side of things.)

---

So what you need is either

```
\draw
  (0,0) node [label=below:$\bullet$] {} -- 
  (2,0) node [label={[label position=below, xshift=1pt]$\bullet$}] {};
```

or

```
\draw
  (0,0) node [label=below:$\bullet$] {} -- 
  (2,0) node [label={[xshift=1pt]below:$\bullet$}] {};
```

or, if all your labels should be placed `below` by default,

```
\draw[label position=below]
  (0,0) node [label=$\bullet$] {} --
  (2,0) node [label={[xshift=1pt]$\bullet$}] {};
```

### Code

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\tikzset{nodes=draw, every label/.append style={help lines, draw}}
\begin{document}
\tikz
  \draw
    (0,0) node [label=below:$\bullet$] {} --
    (2,0) node [label={[label position=below, xshift=1pt]$\bullet$}] {};

\tikz
  \draw
    (0,0) node [label=below:$\bullet$] {} --
    (2,0) node [label={[xshift=1pt]below:$\bullet$}] {};

\tikz
  \draw[label position=below]
    (0,0) node [label=$\bullet$] {} --
    (2,0) node [label={[xshift=1pt]$\bullet$}] {};
\end{document}
```

Comment: "The other label is placed with its top (below → anchor=south) ..." Should it be "below → anchor=north"?

Comment: @Lorents You're absolutely correct.